# I want to make a text converter to unicode converter. The code was going pretty well but I am stuck at changing as '\' is shown invalid

Tags: javascript, string, if-statement, html-entities

```
else if (arr2[i] == ']') {
  mainarr.push('े')
} else if (arr2[i] == '}') {
  mainarr.push('ै')
} else if (arr2[i] == '\') {
  mainarr.push('्')
}
```

I want to make a text converter to Unicode converter. The code was going pretty well but I am stuck at changing as '' is shown invalid. Any way I can type '/'?

Answer (score 2):

Backslash is often interpreted as an "indication of literal next" - meaning that the next character should NOT be interpreted.
In the case above, I would guess that the compiler (and your IDE) is thinking that you meant to say that the single quote is literal.

To fix, make it a double backslash (aka, a literal backslash):

```
} else if (arr2[i] == '\\') {
```